# Setting Precision in SQL SUM Statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, gridview, sum

I have a SQL SUM that I am also dividing, but I want to set the precision at the tenth position so for example 10.1 rather than 10.12.  How would you go about doing this?  Here is my SQL statement:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT PAINT_LINE, SUM(HOURS_REQUIRED/WORKING_DAYS) AS HOURS_REQUIRED,
  TO_CHAR(WEEK_START, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS WEEK_START FROM 
 DCSI.PAINTYEARLYPAINTHRSPROJECTIONS WHERE USER_ID = :UserID AND WEEK_START>=SYSDATE-7
  AND WEEK_START<=SYSDATE+63 GROUP BY WEEK_START, PAINT_LINE ORDER BY WEEK_START DESC, PAINT_LINE
```

I want to set HOURS_REQUIRED to a tenth precision but I have no idea how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to format in SQL(first step) or in GridView(last step)?

Comment: The end result is going to show up in a GridView.  This would be the SelectCommand from the GridView DataSource.

Comment: I'm asking because you can format the GridView without changing the value in the DataSource(f.e. [`ToString` or `String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

ROUND(SUM(HOURS_REQUIRED/WORKING_DAYS),1) AS HOURS_REQUIRED

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to cast it to a numeric with the right precision:

```
cast(<val> as numeric(8,1))
```

for instance.

In you case, this would be:

```
cast(SUM(HOURS_REQUIRED/WORKING_DAYS) as numeric(8, 1)) AS HOURS_REQUIRED
```